# Linux watch command "no such file or directory"

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

In Linux I'm trying to monitor all subdirectories of the current directory and output their file counts. The command I currently have is:

```
watch 'for FILE in `find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | grep -v "unwanted\|directories\|here"`; do echo -n $FILE " "; find $FILE -type f | wc -l; done | column -t'
```

This works perfectly, except occasionally I get this error,

```
find: `FILE_NAME': No such file or directory
```

Where FILE_NAME is the name of a file in one of the subdirectories.

Does anyone know why this would happen and how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible `FILE_NAME` is being deleted by something else? `find` has a race condition where a file can be deleted after `find` has determined it is in the requested directory, but before it can be tested with one of the primaries (in this case, `-type f`).

Comment: @chepner That's probably the cause. One of the reasons that I'm monitoring the directories is to make sure that files are being cleaned up properly. Is there a work-around for this?

Comment: None that I'm aware of. It's just a warning from `find` saying that it can no longer find a file it wouldn't be reporting anyway. You could just suppress `find`'s standard error with `find $FILE -type f 2> /dev/null | wc -l;`

Answer (score 1):

This only uses bash builtins (but AFAIK the only bashism is export -f, so you can use /bin/sh if you want to mangle it into an ugly, unreadable one-liner)

```
#!/bin/bash
myfunc(){
for DIR in "$1/"*; do
    case "$DIR" in
        unwanted|dirs)continue;;
        *)[ -d "$DIR" ] && { 
            printf "%30s    " "$DIR"
            i=0
            for FILE in "$DIR/"*; do
                [ -f "$FILE" ] && i=$((i+1))
            done
            echo $i
        };;
    esac
done
}
export -f myfunc
watch myfunc "$HOME"
```

Note that anything that could be a file name with spaces is double quoted, to prevent trying to stat 2 directories: Program and Files instead of "Program Files".  It is best practice to double quote variables that have any chance of having separators (btw you can have tabs and newline characters in file names + some really weird stuff - pretty much anything but "/" )

Answer (score 0):

Your command does not handle spaces in filenames.

Avoid running `for x in $(find)...`, or at least set IFS to `$'\n'` when running the loop.

Since you only seem to care for the immediate subdirectories, you don't even need to use `find` for the loop values:

```
watch 'for FILE in *; do [ -d "$FILE" ] && { echo -n $FILE " "; find $FILE -type f | wc -l; } done | column -t'
```

(you can use a more complex pattern instead of `*`, or even filter with `echo "$FILE" | grep` inside the loop if you need more specific matching)

Comment: All true, but it's not clear that space-containing file names are the immediate problem here.

Comment: @SirAthos Thanks for the suggestion. There aren't any spaces in the current directory (or its subdirectories), but I will keep that in mind in the future!